# get_the_date() returns english Year & Day when language is Arabic

Tags: php, wordpress

I changed my WordPress language to Arabic, Now `get_the_date()` returns `يناير 30, 2020` (half Arabic & half english) but I need to get date full Arabic like: `يناير ٣٠, ٢٠٢٠`

How can I do this?

Comment: You have to change the language from dashboard language settings !!!..
**Dashboard >> Settings >> General Settings**, then use below code.
`<?php echo get_the_date( 'd M'); ?>`

Comment: `setlocale(LC_TIME, “ar-EG.UTF-8”);
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", get_post_time('U'));`